# AStar Search - How to change directions and costs?

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, a-star

So, in the A* search implementation that I am working on, I can use the directions for pathfinding as up, left, right, down as such:

```
#define the moving direction: up /left /right /down
xs = (0, -1, 1, 0)
ys = (-1, 0, 0, 1)
```

How do I change the moving direction to: up, left, right, down, upper left, lower left, upper right and lower right  ?

As for the cost, with the up, left, right, down I have 1.0, but if I had to have the cost as 2.0 for directions: upper left, lower left, upper right and lower right, how can I implement that?

```
def get_cost(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    if x1 == x2 or y1 == y2:
      return 1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you can just simply check and see if you're in the same position in each axis or not.

```
def get_cost(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    if (x1 == x2 and y1 != y2) or (x1 != x2 and y1 == y2):
        # you have just moved in one axis
        return 1.0
    else:
        return 2.0
```

Comment: How do I change the directions? How do I add more directions to this?

Comment: calculate x_dir = x2-x1 and y_dir = y2-y1. based on the results you can find the direction. for instance, if x_dir = 1 and y_dir = 0, it has moved to right

Comment: I need to manually define the directions.   `#define the moving direction: up /left /right /down
xs = (0, -1, 1, 0)
ys = (-1, 0, 0, 1)`

This is defining as up/left/right/down.

Comment: your new directions are gonna look like this:
up/left/right/down/upper-right/upper-left/lower-right/lower-left
xs = (0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1)
ys = (-1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1)